# FILE A COMPLAINT already

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Anyone can file a complaint, but Coudert says the idea of bringing the allegations himself “felt weird because I am not … based in the U.S. and I know none of these people.” But after he called out NAS on Twitter, President Marcia McNutt responded: “**FILE A COMPLAINT already.**”

Source: Science
[National academy may eject two famous scientists for sexual harassment](https://www.sciencemag.org/news/2021/04/national-academy-may-eject-two-famous-scientists-sexual-harassment)

What is the meaning of the phrase "FILE A COMPLAINT already"? Does it mean "There is already a complaint filed (as opposed to what Coudert felt - 'there is no complaint that I know")"?

The problem in my understanding probably comes from the difficulty of my grasping what Coudert said - "the idea of bringing the allegations himself." I am not sure what he actually means. It sounds that he would make a complaint against himself. It's odd and I believe I've misunderstood the grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"FILE A COMPLAINT already" is a command to file a complaint, and it has the implied emotion of someone who is "tired of waiting" and "just want to get this [thing] done and over"

Other examples:
"DO YOUR WORK already"
"RELEASE THE VIDEO already"

as for "bringing the allegations himself", that means he is coming to the institution and bringing over the allegations (the complaints; the offending matters) himself (i.e. not waiting for somebody else to do it)

Comment: Thank you. So "already" is an informal usage that is used to express exasperation or impatience (like "Let's go already!")?

Comment: yes, exactly as you said!

Comment: This use of "already" is US English. A UK or AU speaker would just leave out the "already".

Comment: I think this usage came to US English via Yiddish.